# Memory Order Policy for Atomic variable in C

Tags: c, atomic, memory-barriers, stdatomic

I am writing some code where a timer increments a global variable which maintains my internal system tick count. There are other api's like getCount(), addToSystemTick(), incrementSystemTick(). I am trying to use atomic variable for system_tick_counter. My question is for adding or fetching the variable what memory order policy should I enforce?

Answer (score 2):

You could follow the convention of `<stdatomic.h>` and provide `seq_cst` by default, and have `getCount_explicit(memory_order)` that allows passing the caller's choice of memory order.

But for a system-tick variable, maybe `relaxed` would be appropriate since it's not obvious that you'd ever use this for synchronization between threads.

Maybe if you were also using those timer values as sequence numbers, so code like this could make sense:

```
    if (getCount_explicit(memory_order_acquire) >= x)
         read other things updated before that tick number
```

If all modifications are atomic RMWs, then it forms a release-sequence, and `acq_rel` increments could give the necessary properties for that to be guaranteed safe, I think.  Totally depends on your use-case whether that's relevant.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I will look into its use cases more.